# Docker Copy - Windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am currently trying to copy a folder and its sub directories to a docker container but all that copies in is the folder structure "`obj\Docker\empty`"

I am running the command in Powershell from `D:\Sites\Web.API` and the command is:
`docker cp . eac334ba8bf6:./inetpub/wwwroot/Web.API`.

My .dockerignore file has this in it

```
!obj\Docker\publish\*
!obj\Docker\empty\
```

I'm pretty new to this so may be something silly but currently all out of ideas !

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is file system permissions. Have you tried to copy it somewhere else?